# Can't install arcpy in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, arcpy

I have ArcGIS Pro installed, which includes the installed Python packages. I am trying to learn Python and would like to use the ArcPy functions. I have never used Jupyter Notebook before, but to get started, I created a new Python 3 file. I entered the code to install `arcpy` but received an error.

```
pip install arcpy 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement arcpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for arcpy

import arcpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcpy'
```

I know I am missing a link somewhere, and I am guessing it has to do with environments. How can I reference the `arcpy` packages that are installed in my ArcGIS Pro program files?

Answer (score 2):

### Using "Non-ArcGIS Pro" Conda Environment

I assume that you use an Anaconda or Miniconda installation not provided by ArcGIS Pro, otherwise `arcpy` should already be available and there is no need to install it.

**Note:** If you want to use ArcGIS Pro's conda environment, scroll down to *Using ArcGIS Pro's Conda Enviroment* or *Using Jupyter Notebook from within ArcGIS Pro*.

To install `arcpy`, you need to use `conda` instead of `pip`. As far as I know `arcpy` is not available in the Python Package Index (`pip`'s repository).

#### Initial Setup

Open **Anaconda Prompt** (or any command prompt if `conda` can be found through the `PATH` variable).

First you need a conda environment. Use the following command to create an environment called `esri-notebook` (can be any name):

```
conda create -n esri-notebook
```

Then activate the environment using:

```
conda activate esri-notebook
```

Install Jupyter Lab (or Notebook) with:

```
conda install jupyterlab
conda update --all
```

Install `arcpy` with:

```
conda install arcpy -c esri
```

Run Jupyter Lab with:

```
jupyter lab
```

*Or*, run Jupyter Notebook with:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Your browser will open with Jupyter Lab or Notebook.

#### Using Jupyter Lab/Notebook

Open **Anaconda Prompt** (or any command prompt if `conda` can be found through the `PATH` variable). Activate the environment:

```
conda activate esri-notebook
```

Run Jupyter Lab with:

```
jupyter lab
```

*Or*, run Jupyter Notebook with:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Your browser will open with Jupyter Lab or Notebook.

### Using ArcGIS Pro's Conda Enviroment

Open **Python Command Prompt**. `arcpy` is available (no setup needed).

Then start Jupyter Notebook using:

```
jupyter notebook
```

### Using Jupyter Notebook from within ArcGIS Pro

You can also create a notebook from within ArcGIS Pro and `arcpy` should be available to use it without any further setup. Find the Python button within the Analysis ribbon:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out a solution with using ArcPy in Jupyter notebooks launched through their app because I couldn't find a way to change the Python interpreter. However, when I open a Jupyter notebook in VS Code, I was able to do that.

Comment: Can you show the steps using VS Code in your answer?