# How to import (install) arcpy and geopandas and successfully use them in one script?

Tags: anaconda, geopandas, arcpy

In my script, I want to use both arcpy and geopandas. So I tried to clone the environment from ArcGIS Pro (2.8.0) first and then install geopandas via anaconda. Even though the geopandas has been successfully installed, when calling the library, errors occured.
Any suggestions about setting up these two libraries are really appreciated.

Comment: I could install each of them separately. But how to install both of them into the same environment?

Comment: there's no reason why this wouldn't work. just make sure you install pip in the same environment as geopandas and use that environment's pip when installing arcpy. we need more information if you want specific advice though.

Answer (score 0):

In case you tried it through ArcGIS Pro's user interface, you are better off to do this in the Python Command Prompt.

1. Open your **Python Command Prompt**
2. Then following commands (assuming the new environment's name is `arcgispro-py3-gpd`):

```sh
activate arcgispro-py3
conda create --name arcgispro-py3-gpd --clone arcgispro-py3
activate arcgispro-py3-gpd
conda install geopandas
```

You may get some warnings about inconsistent environment. See this [ArcGIS Pro Idea](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/installing-geopandas-on-jupyter-notebook/idc-p/1164427) starting the thread with [this comment](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/installing-geopandas-on-jupyter-notebook/idc-p/1162790/highlight/true#M19293).

---

You can also install `arcpy` in your own "non-ArcGIS Pro" Conda environment. (ArcGIS Pro still needs to be installed on the same computer.)

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71914479/42659) (of the question [Can't install arcpy in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71802996/42659)) I am showing how to install `geopandas` and `jupyterlab` in a "non-ArcGIS Pro" Conda environment.

Comment: Hi there, I tried the main part to install arcpy and geopandas. It does not work. Arcpy can be import successfully, but geopandas cannot. It shows some information like below:                              
                               Package pyshp conflicts for:
esri/win-64::arcgis==1.8.5=py37_1783 -> pyshp[version='>=2']
esri/win-64::arcpy==2.8=py37_arcgispro_29734 -> arcgis[version='>=1.8.*'] -> pyshp[version='>=2']
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.

Comment: I am checking the rest methodologies.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/moosetraveller/d99daeb01cb53005ccece66e1b326896?permalink_comment_id=4167791#gistcomment-4167791