# How to install ArcGIS API for Python without Anaconda variants

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, arcgis

I have come across [ArcGIS api for python](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/) and it looks great for visualizing nice maps that can be generated. At first I thought it was only available through ArcGIS Pro. However, I have come across this [YouTube](https://youtu.be/jLn-J3y8A1s) video and [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71914479/13642249) with great instructions to install with anaconda. Unfortunately, installing all of Anaconda is not the best option for speedy map renderings, and I tried to install with an python environment `python3 -m pip install arcgis`.

I have tried testing this pip install with jupyter notebook as suggested from this [post](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/install-and-set-up/#test-your-install-with-jupyter-notebook), but get the following Attribute Error:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
my_gis = GIS()
m = my_gis.map()

m

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\LocationVenues\py_venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py:920, in IPythonDisplayFormatter.__call__(self, obj)
    918 method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    919 if method is not None:
--> 920     method()
    921     return True

File ~\LocationVenues\py_venv\lib\site-packages\arcgis\widgets\_mapview\_mapview.py:948, in MapView._ipython_display_(self)
    942 """Override the parent ipython display function that is called
    943 whenever is displayed in the notebook. Display a blank area
    944 below the map widget that can be controlled via a display handler
    945 set to self._preview_image_display_handler.
    946 """
    947 self._setup_gis_properties(self.gis)
--> 948 super(MapView, self)._ipython_display_()
    949 self._preview_image_display_handler = display(
    950     HTML(self._assemble_img_preview_html_str("")),
    951     display_id="preview-" + str(self._uuid),
    952 )
    953 self._preview_html_embed_display_handler = display(
    954     HTML(self._assemble_html_embed_html_str("")),
    955     display_id="preview-html-" + str(self._uuid),
    956 )

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_ipython_display_'
```

I'm unsure of the distinction between installing using Anaconda and doing so in a separate Python environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing a specific version of ipywidgets, I was able to render the map as shown in the test [example](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/install-and-set-up/#test-your-install-with-jupyter-notebook) after finding a closed [issue](https://github.com/yWorks/yfiles-jupyter-graphs/issues/18) for the error stating the missing attribute. The following are my steps with python 3.9.7 on Windows 10 with PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\kyrlon\Desktop> python -m venv py_venv
(py_venv) PS C:\Users\kyrlon\Desktop>.\py_venv\Scripts\activate
(py_venv) PS C:\Users\kyrlon\Desktop> python -m pip install --upgrade pip 
(py_venv) PS C:\Users\kyrlon\Desktop> python -m pip install ipywidgets==7.6.0
(py_venv) PS C:\Users\kyrlon\Desktop> python -m pip install arcgis
(py_venv) PS C:\Users\kyrlon\Desktop> jupyter notebook
```

Notebook contents:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
my_gis = GIS()
m = my_gis.map()
m
```

[image]